# Suddenly my project is getting error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, reactiveui

I am developing a windows phone 7 application using ReactiveUI library.. I have create a one sample application and I was working on it last few months. Daily i open the project and do some modifications. Today also I am doing some sample in my project. Suddenly I am getting this error.

> Could not load type 'ReactiveUI.RxApp' from assembly 'ReactiveUI_WP7,
>   Version=4.6.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I don't know what is going on. before 10 min it is working fine. Please help me to resolve this problem. I have done more than 50 examples in this project. Please help me..

Comment: Is the file that holds that class still there?

Comment: Hi @Sayse Thanks for reply.. I Can not understand.. Please tell me where I have to check??

Comment: If its a dll, check the dll is there. It also could be a rogue `{` or `}` somewhere I believe

Comment: Hi @Sayse.. I have checked all the dll.. All are available in my project. And also I have check with { and }.. No errors.. Please any other idea??

Comment: It could be any type of bracket, I am assuming you are only getting this error in one class file within your project

Comment: Restart Visual Studio and your PC